# Dropbox or Drive for accesing and syncing offline content

Tags: dropbox, google-drive-api

I am having some issues with a use case I thought would be simple. We have a set of documents that I want to store in the cloud. They should be synced and updated for usage in an Android tablet on the field.

So I am testing Dropbox and Drive on a Nexus tablet right now and I see the following issues/ questions:

1. For both of them it seems as I can not select a folder for syncing. I have to set the start preference or offline content flag for each file. This is quite a lot of work and also if we would add a new document we would have to mark this on all devices manually. This seems very cumbersome. If I could just set a folder as offline supported this would not be a problem since new files would automatically be included when there is coverage? Am I missing something here, offline folders seems like a pretty basic scenario?
2. Lets say that I stick with the manual offline selection for each file or manage to solve offline folders. The next question is. If I am offline and want to access a link to a shared document, I have a link to my pdf in another application or document and the doc exists in offline mode in my device but I have no coverage. Will the link still work or is internet access a requirement for the link to work and I have to browse to the Dropbox or Drive Applications to find the document manually.

Thanks in advance for any advice